# How to check if an array index contains a value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some values in different spots. I want to check if there is a value in the index then put it in a new array starting at 0 then put in index 1 then next value at index 2 and so on. I need to shorten it and move them all to the left really.

```
Array ( [0] => 53 [1] => [2] => 55 [3] => 76 [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => )
```

The new array would be:

```
newArray ( [0] => 53 [1] =>55 [2] => 76)
```

Maybe something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($questionWorth); $i++)
{ 
    if($questionWorth[$i] has a value)
    {
       put it in new array starting at index zero
       then increment the index of new array
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "maybe something like this" solution is fine.

Comment: but i dont no how to implement that solution in php...

Comment: `if ($questionWorth[$i] != '') $newArray[] = $questionWorth[$i];`

Comment: "but i dont no how to implement that solution in php" --- and because you are lazy - you want us to do your job for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only get values that is not `NULL` or empty you could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like this:

```
$array = array(76, NULL, NULL, 56);
// remove empty values from array, notice that since no callback
// is supplied values that evaluates to false will be removed
$array = array_filter($array);
// since array_filter will preserve the array keys
// you can use array_values() to reindex the array numerically
$array = array_values($array);
// prints Array ( [0] => 76 [1] => 56 ) 
print_r($array);
```

Comment: its doesnt work that way though, it makes it ([0]=>76, [3]=>56) instead of 0 and one

Comment: @DinoBicBoi - Now it should work, you only need to use `array_values()` after you have filtered out the NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
           array_filter($yourArray)
```

It will remove all empty values for you

Comment: Nope , it will remove all the empty values with their keys

Answer (score 0):

Try  `array_filter` which makes exactly this

```
var_dump(array_filter(array(0 => 55, 1 => 60, 2 => null)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an index has a value, do this :

```
$variable = array ([0] => 53, [1] => , [2] => 55, [3] => 76, [4] => , [5] => , [6] => , [7] => )

foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($key.' => '.$value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this: `if ( $array [$i] )`, and then put the value in another array with another counter that starts from 0.

```
$array = array(76, NULL, NULL, 56);
$count = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
{ 
    if($array[$i])
    {
        $arr[$count] = $array[$i];
        $count++;
    }
};

print_r($array);
print_r($arr);
```